# How to create a lookup to another table based on two fields in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Table 1                                 Table 2
Name                                    Effective Date 
Effective Date                          End Date 
End Date                                Number of Work Days
```

I need help on how to create a lookup that says

Select 
Table1.Name

If Table1.EffectiveDate = Table2.EffectiveDate 
AND Table1.EndDate = Table2.EndDate 
THEN Pull the Number of Work Days AS WORK_DAYS

I can do this with IF(AND( Statement in Excel but I am having a hard time figuring out what statements to use in SQL SERVER with no primary key.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is not much in the way of details here. It would be much better if you posted ddl, sample data and desired output. This article is a great place to read about that. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Guessing on the requirements I think it is this simple. I would strongly urge you not to have tables with no primary key. Those are called heaps and they are a real pain to work with.

```
select [Number of Work Days]
from Table2 
join Table1 on Table1.EffectiveDate = Table2.EffectiveDate AND Table1.EndDate = Table2.EndDate
```